# How to run Colima with docker-compose in Pycharm (or other Jetbrains project)

Tags: python, debugging, docker-compose, pycharm, colima

When switching from Docker Desktop to [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) I encountered problems with setting up Run configuration in Pycharm thru Docker-compose feature.
[Example setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcpHa.png)

I keep getting this error from Pycharm:

```
no such service: 
container:9200f38c022e09065fbb972683cd8843c6faedf4b722ee573ea34303f604b843:ro 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Versions:

Colima v 0.3.2
docker-compose v 2.2.3
PyCharm 2021.3.2 (Professional Edition)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution yet but I believe the culprit is that pycharm uses syntax for specifying containers unsupported by your (our) setup.
Pycharm integrates with `docker-compose` like this:

1. docker container with helper scripts in volume is created

```
$ docker ps  -a
...
346cc60545f6 aac5779e964d  "/bin/sh" Created pycharm_helpers_PY-213.6777.50
```

2. it creates it's own overlay. My project `docker-compose.yml` is `version: 2`, pycharm's override is:

```
$ cat /Users/.../Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3/tmp/docker-compose.override.2.yml
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    command:
    - "python"
    - "-V"
    entrypoint: ""
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
    restart: "no"
    volumes: []
    volumes_from:
    - "container:346cc60545f6e7955661fc6f8f578c6f3f871a7330b068cb35224efbee05aae7:ro"
```

3. is calls `docker-compose` with the overlay:

```
docker-compose \
  -f /Users/.../projects/pythonProject1/docker-compose.yml \
  -f /Users/.../Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3/tmp/docker-compose.override.9.yml \
  run --rm --no-deps app
```

Now if I try `container:` syntax with `docker run` I get an error:

```
$ docker run --rm -it \
  --volumes-from container:346cc60545f6e7955661fc6f8f578c6f3f871a7330b068cb35224efbee05aae7:ro \
  python:3.9 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: 346cc60545f6e7955661fc6f8f578c6f3f871a7330b068cb35224efbee05aae7:ro.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

With `container:` prefix removed it works:

```
$ docker run --rm -it \
  --volumes-from 346cc60545f6e7955661fc6f8f578c6f3f871a7330b068cb35224efbee05aae7:ro \
  python:3.9 bash
root@0e5ba9104c62:/# mount | grep pycharm
/dev/disk/by-label/data-volume on /opt/.pycharm_helpers type ext4 (ro,relatime)
root@0e5ba9104c62:/# ls /opt/.pycharm_helpers/
Dockerfile       docstring_formatter.py       pockets       pycharm_matplotlib_backend      six.py
MathJax          epydoc               profiler      pycodestyle.py              sphinxcontrib
__pycache__      extra_syspath.py         py2ipnb_converter.py  pydev                   syspath.py
check_all_test_suite.py  generator3           py2only       python-skeletons            third_party
conda_packaging_tool.py  icon-robots.txt          py3only       remote_sync.py              tools
coverage_runner      packaging_tool.py        pycharm       rest_runners                typeshed
coveragepy       pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl  pycharm_display   setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl  virtualenv.pyz
```

But with `docker-compose.yml` `version: 3` I get different error

```
error during connect: Get "http://unix:2375/Users/.../.colima/docker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dpythonproject1%22%3Atrue%7D%7D&limit=0": dial tcp: lookup unix on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Pycharm's `docker-compose` for 3.8 doesn't use `container:` syntax anymore:

```
$ cat /Users/.../Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3/tmp/docker-compose.override.9.yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    command:
    - "python"
    - "-V"
    entrypoint: ""
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
    - "pycharm_helpers_PY-213.6777.50:/opt/.pycharm_helpers"
volumes:
  pycharm_helpers_PY-213.6777.50: {}
```

Wrapper script replacing the overlay with the one with `contaner:` prefix stripped would likely help us for `version: 2`, but the problem with `version: 3.8` would persist.